OpenStack Horizon service is not accessible
A while ago we configured OpenStack services on a RISC-V-machine cluster, and we were able to access the Dashboard both through the web and the terminal.
Since we're running OpenStack on a RISC-V machine (LicheePia4), sometimes when we were running more than two instances simultaneously, Horizon would crash, although a simple sudo systemctl reboot on the controller node would fix the issue.
Last time it crashed, a reboot didn't fix the issue, and now we are trying to understand why we cannot access the dashboard.
Here's a walk-through of what we tried:

Checked that Horizon required services (Identity, Apache2 and Memcache) are correctly running.
Synchronized machine clock using date -s (not ideal, but we couldn't make an NTP server work)
Checked that Horizon, Identity and Apache2 configuration files match OpenStack documentation.

More info: /var/log/openstack-dashboard/ is not producing any logs, but Apache2 it is.
root@controller01:/var/log/apache2# [Mon Aug 05 11:08:09.643379 2024] [ssl:warn] [pid 1243:tid 274098991136] AH01909: 10.0.0.1:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Aug 05 11:08:09.672933 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1243:tid 274098991136] AH00489: Apache/2.4.58 (Debian) OpenSSL/3.2.2-dev mod_wsgi/5.0.0 Python/3.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Aug 05 11:08:09.673176 2024] [core:notice] [pid 1243:tid 274098991136] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Aug 05 11:09:17.139586 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 6046:tid 273913200928] /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py:267: RemovedInDjango50Warning: The USE_L10N setting is deprecated. Starting with Django 5.0, localized formatting of data will always be enabled. For example Django will display numbers and dates using the format of the current locale.
[Mon Aug 05 11:09:17.139732 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 6046:tid 273913200928]   warnings.warn(USE_L10N_DEPRECATED_MSG, RemovedInDjango50Warning)
[Mon Aug 05 11:09:18.249158 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 6046:tid 273913200928] /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/debreach/__init__.py:6: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.


SOLUTION
Since Horizon wasn't generating any log files (should be located in /var/log/openstack-dashboard/) I went through Apache2 logs and found that Horizon was getting hanged up when calling Neutron. Therefore I looked into Neutrons' log and found that a vxlan configuration was misplaced in /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini since provider network configuration doesn't need vxlan:
type_drivers = vxlan,vlan,flat
tenant_network_types = vxlan

Replacing vxlan from both parameters for local solves the issue.
